# Ionic sass per component. Sass compilation. how to change?

Tags: angular, webpack, ionic2

Hi I'm new in Ionic and I've noticed that styles are not processed the same way as in regular angular 2.0 app.

What I want is actually ng2 behaviour, where I can define webpack loader to handle sass files instead of one global "main.css" thaty appears "magically" 
How can i disable this, change configuration etc.

I have allready ejected webpack configuration to project folder and changed package.json:

```
  "config": {
    "ionic_bundler": "webpack",
    "ionic_webpack": "./webpack.config.js"

  },
```

I need more to support custom sass compilation.

Comment: Can you tell us what is your requirement? why do you need to do above? What is your goal?

Comment: sure. The goal is to use additional loader during "scsss" processing.
In details I want to use resolve-url-loader, which I've been successfully using in my previous ng2 projects and earlier in angularjs 1.5.
In my opinion keeping resources that are not shared across components in a global directory  "breaks encapsulation". I want to keep them in this same folder as ts, html and css (or in folder resources in that directory).
It was realized for example here:
https://github.com/bunny1985/typescript_webpack_angular1_seed
and here:
https://github.com/bunny1985/angularSeed2
for angular 2